# How to prevent generating all javadoc files when there is only some changes

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, jautodoc

I'm using JAutodoc for auto commenting java files in eclipse neon 2.
I have created javadoc file by using :

[image]

Then i change some java files and generate javadoc again.
When i check git repo, i observe "all doc" is modified instead of only changed files.

The problem is that javadoc generates all files and i want javadoc to generate only changed java files.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`javadoc` will regenerate all documents regardless of whether source files have changed. Given specific arguments, `javadoc` processing can be restricted to a select set of files either by package name and/or file/pathname, but not by file conditions (i.e. has/has not changed, timestamps, etc.). You can find out more about controlling `javadoc` by reviewing [javadoc - The Java API Documentation Generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html).

While it is possible to create scripts that limit `javadoc` processing to changed files only, it is not recommended. Consider a class that has moved to a different package. Running `javadoc` on that `.java` file alone would not update references to that class in other parts (e.g. package summaries, `@link` references).

Since Javadocs are artifacts normally generated from source code, tracking them in your repository has no benefit, as far as revision control is concerned. You could just exclude them via `.gitignore` (once you have removed them with `git rm`).

Comment: I have already searched javadoc documentation, but i couldln't find specific arguments. @Frelling

Comment: The lead in to my answer was a bit ambiguous, I have rephrased it.